# Program to find next immediate prime number

Tags: c

```
void main()    
{
   int n,i,j,flag=0,out;

   clrscr();

   printf("enter the num\n");

   scanf("%d",&n);

   for(i=n+1;i<=100;i++)
   {

      flag=0;

      for(j=2;j<i;j++)
      {
         if(i%j==0)
         {
            flag=1;
            break;
         }
      }

      if(flag==0)
      {
         printf("next prime is:%d",i);
         break;
      }
   }

   getch();

}
```

In this code if i entered input as 8 . Then i=9,j=2 
then 9%2==0 the condition becomes false and 9 will be printed as next prime number which is wrong answer.Please give me correct solution for this program.

Comment: heh? I did not understand.

Comment: @cad `then 9%2==0 the condition becomes false`..so you both are correct :)

Comment: did you miss the `if(flag==0)` check?

Comment: i can't able to understand the concept behind ths anyone explain ths pls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I checked your program and it produces the correct output.

Now for explanation, for the case you described

> In this code if i entered input as 8 . Then i=9,j=2 then 9%2==0 the
>   condition becomes false and 9 will be printed as next prime number
>   which is wrong answer.

So, it will get (9%2 == 0) => false. Then it will not check the `if(flag==0)` condition and print 9 as next prime. instead, it will increase j and continue looping till `j<i`.

[image]

Hence, it will produce correct answer.

Comment: The outer loop ought to ignore even numbers, since no even numbers (other than 2) are prime. So, at the top of the outer loop initialize i to n+1 if n is even, and n+2 if n is odd. As follows:
    i = n%2 ? n+2 : n+1;
Then skip even numbers by iterating by 2 as follows:
    for (i = n%2 ? n+2 : n+1; ; i+=2) 

This will yield the same results, but in half the time.

Answer (score 1):

Check the following code :

```
void main()
{
    int n,i,j;
    clrscr();

    printf("Enter the number : ");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    for(i=n+1;;i++)
    {
        for(j=2;j<i;j++)
        {
            if(i%j==0)
                break;
        }

        if(j==i)
        {
            printf("The next prime number is :%d",i);
            break;
        }
    }
    getch();
}
```